# Deserialize JSON Array to object

Tags: c#, json

I've been starting at this for a while and can't quite seem to get my head round it, essentially I have a JSON array which I want to decode into the Notifications object, the exception is:

*"An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WpfApplication2.Notifications' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly."*

```
public Notifications Notes;

// HTTP request gets the JSON below.

//EXCEPTION ON THIS LINE
Notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notifications>(responseString);

    public class Notifications 
    {

        [JsonProperty("note_id")]
       public int note_id { get; set;}
        [JsonProperty("sender_id")]
        public int sender_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("receiver_id")]
        public int receiver_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("document_id")]
        public int document_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("search_name")]
        public string search_name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("unread")]
        public int unread { get; set; }
    }
```

The Json retrieved is:

```
[
  {
    "note_id": "5",
    "sender_id": "3",
    "receiver_id": "1",
    "document_id": "102",
    "unread": "1"
  },
  {
    "note_id": "4",
    "sender_id": "2",
    "receiver_id": "1",
    "document_id": "101",
    "unread": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe because your array is unnamed, i.e. that it should be something like `{ "arrayname": [ {...}, {...} ] }` ?

Comment: You need to deserialize to an array or collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should deserialize it to a list:

```
public IList<Notifications> Notes;

Notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notifications>>(responseString);
```

Should work!

Comment: Could also be an array.

Comment: Erm i'm not sure which one to pick here they both work!

Answer (score 2):

Your call tries to deserialize a single object. The expected Json for such an object would be a dictionary of values, which is what the error message is saying.

You should try to deserialize to a IEnumerable-derived collection instead, eg an array or list:

```
Notifications[] Notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Notifications[]>(responseString);
```

or

```
IList<Notifications> Notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Notifications>>(responseString);
```

Comment: I've upvoted this as it also works, Charles got there just before though hope this seems fair?